# How can I straightforwardly include JSON in an HTML5 data-* attribute so that the JSON remains human-readable as well as machine-readable?

Tags: html, json, encoding

**JSON** utilises double-quotes.

My environmental constraint is that I must place HTML attributes in double-quotes.

I know I can encode JSON using:

- URL Encoding (via `encodeURI(JSONToEncode)`)
- Base64 encoding (via `window.btoa(JSONToEncode)`)

But how can I straightforwardly include JSON in an HTML5 `data-*` attribute so that it remains (maximally) human-readable as well as machine-readable?

**eg.** How can I include this:

```
{"chosenStarter" : "bhajis", "chosenMain" : "madras", "chosenDessert" : "kulfi"}
```

in this:

```
data-menu="[... VALUE HERE...]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One straightforward human-readable approach is to use **angular quotes**:

```
data-menu="{«chosenStarter» : «bhajis», «chosenMain» : «madras», «chosenDessert» : «kulfi»}"
```

and then convert to **JSON** with:

```
const myJSON = myElement.dataset.menu.replace(/«|»/g, '"');
```